# Prometheus don't show correct result

Tags: java, prometheus, prometheus-java

I'am trying to send metricks to Prometheus from my Java code. I use MeterRegistry class for it. Metrick and tags what I send look like

```
[tag(user-status=ACTIVE), tag(strategy-type=POOL), tag(verified=true), tag(subscription-status=INACTIVE)] 10
[tag(user-status=ACTIVE), tag(strategy-type=POOL), tag(verified=true), tag(subscription-status=ACTIVE)] 21
[tag(user-status=ACTIVE), tag(strategy-type=POOL), tag(verified=true)] 15
```

But if I open my Prometheus endpoint I can see only this result.

```
# HELP users  
# TYPE users gauge
users{application="mng",strategy_type="POOL",subscription_status="INACTIVE",user_status="ACTIVE",verified="true",} 10.0
users{application="mng",strategy_type="POOL",subscription_status="ACTIVE",user_status="ACTIVE",verified="true",} 21.0
```

Where is one metric with fewer tags?

Comment: You don't have established a subscription for that tag?!

Comment: Yes. That tag should be without a subscription.